# C++/CLI: How wrap unmanaged class with virtual methods to managed and use that from C#?

Tags: c++, callback, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I am new to C++/CLI and I would like to know how I can wrap unmanaged C++ class with virtual methods to managed and use that from C#?

Unmanaged C++ class:

```
class IProgression
{
public:
    virtual ~IProgression(void) {}
    virtual void sendProgression(int amount, int present) = 0;
};
```

sendProgression method is used to send progress information to C# layer. So it's callback.

I have other unmanaged C++ class where this progression callback is set:

```
virtual void setProgression(IProgression * pIProgression) = 0;
```

So I need to set callback interface from C# to unmanaged C++ via C++/CLI and get progression information back to C# from unmanaged C++ via C++/CLI.

Can someone give advices how to implement this since I'm kind of confused with this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
public interface IManagedProgression {
    void SendProgression(int amount, int present);
};

public class Wrapper : public IProgression {
public:
   Wrapper(IManagedProgression^ c)
   {
       callBack = c;
   }


   void sendProgression(int amount, int present)
   {
       callBack->SendProgression(amount, present);
   }

private:
   gcroot<IManagedProgression^> callBack;
};
```

You can then implement the IManagedProgression in C# or another language and wrap it in a Wrapper object.

Comment: Thank you very much wolle for quick answer. I'm just wondering why Wrapper class don't need to to be defined as ref class in this case? I implemented your suggestion and also that IManagedProgression to C# side. I still have difficulties to wrap that interface to Wrapper object. How I can do that? I'm almost there.

Comment: Probably the managed side should use events, not an interface.  But this will work too.

Comment: Anyone who can guide me with this?